# How do I map a date and uid field from an external table in TYPO3 Extbase?

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm coding a TYPO3 extension with Extbase that is supposed to get data from an external table. I mapped the corresponding fields using the following TypoScript:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence {     
        classes {
            VMFDS\VmfdsLiturgy\Domain\Model\Event {
                mapping {
                    tableName = usrdb_vmfredbb_kool.ko_event
                    columns {
                        id.mapOnProperty = uid
                        startdatum.mapOnProperty = datum
                        title.mapOnProperty = title
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

`startdatum` is a date field with data in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. `id` is a mediumint. Now, while `title` is mapped correctly, `datum` is simply set to 0 (or rather, to 1970-01-01), and `uid` is always 2. Why? How do I tell TYPO3 and its DataMapper about the correct field format?

Answer (score 0):

> datum is simply set to 0 (or rather, to 1970-01-01)

When working with Extbase and actual date fields instead of timestamps you need to properly set the `dbType` in your TCA. You will find more information in the official documentation.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html#dbtype